# Implementing memset: dl register segfault

Tags: c, assembly, nasm, x86-64, memset

I'm implementing `memset` in x86-64 assembly code using `NASM`. When I try to move the value from `rsi` into `dl` I get a segfault.  Can you help me understand why?

Here is what I have so far:

```
    global my_memset

my_memset:

    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp

    xor rax, rax
    xor rcx, rcx
    mov dl, byte [rsi]      ;segfault                                                
    mov rax, rdi
    cmp rdx, 0
    jz end
while:
    inc rcx
    mov byte [rdi], dl
    inc rdi
    cmp rcx, rdx
    jne while
end:
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp

    ret
```

I'm exercising this with a pretty simple `main` function:

```
void    *my_memset(void *data, int value, int size);
int     main()
  {
     char  buffer[100];

     my_memset(buffer, 'm', 100);
     printf("%s\n", buffer);
  }
```

Note that I tried an alternate test with `main` implemented in assembly code, and that seemed to run okay.  Why might this be?  (Please let me know if you'd like me to post that code too.)

Comment: What does rsi contain at that point? You haven't set it to anything.

Comment: i call it in my main so there is the value of  'm' inside, the second argument no?

Comment: Who said the second argument's address is stored in esi?

Comment: thats how it work no? the order is rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8 then r9 i thought this was the "convention"

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: its in my school asm pdf so...

Comment: Is this x86-64 on Windows? Linux?

Answer (score 2):

`esi` holds the second parameter, which is the value to fill the memory area with. (So in your test, rsi holds 'm', or rather its ASCII code)

In this instruction:

```
mov dl, byte [rsi]
```

you try to use that as a *memory address*, so you access the memory location whose address is the ASCII code of 'm'. That causes a segfault.

What you want is to just use `rsi` directly, for example:

```
mov rdx, rsi
```

Also, your current code uses `rdx` for two things - the count, and the byte to fill with. That won't work - it's only one register and it only holds one value. (Note that `dl` means "the lowest byte of `rdx`" - it's not a separate register)

Comment: oh its not a different register, i understand now.  thanks a lot man!!! im will try to make this work now :) thanks again!!!! too bad i cant upvote you

Answer (score 1):

The arguments are `rdi, rsi, rdx, rcx, r8, r9`. You are copying a byte (`char`) pointed to by `rsi` to `dl`, not the value of the register. You could move the whole register to `rdx`:

```
mov rdx, rsi
```

but you are using `rdx` as the count limit register already, thus I suggest you move the value to `rax` instead and store the `al`.

---

Though, in this case for the shortest code and definitely more performant than yours could be to use the string instruction `rep stosb`, making your function into

```
my_memset:
    mov rax, rsi     ; move the byte to al
    mov rcx, rdx     ; move the counter to rcx
    rep stosb        ; repeat store byte from al to [rdi]
                     ; and increase rdi (if direction flag cleared)
                     ; decrease rcx and if rcx is zero, break out
    ret
```

(note this function assumes the *direction flag is cleared*, which it should be).

Comment: i know im not trying to take the void * im leaving it on rdi, i want the second one, the int i have to move it in dl so i can move it again in rdi cause i cant do i move from a memory to a memory.